# Change version of REST API instance in MarkLogic

Tags: rest, marklogic

When creating an instance of REST API (an application), a version (appearing as a prefix) has then to be included in the URL when calling it.
Is there a way to manager several versions (at the same time) of an API? Are we able to change the version number or how is it changed?

The only link I have found is : https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_64988

But it is not pretty clear to me.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is determined by the MarkLogic installation, not something that can be configured. I'll ask Product Management to elaborate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link says, "The version number is only updated when resource addresses and/or parameters have changed. It is not updated when resource addresses and/or parameters are added or removed."

In other words, the REST API will increment the version step if it ever becomes necessary to rename or restructure the addresses of resources.  Ideally, that will never need to happen. If incrementing becomes necessary, the goal will be to maintain a deprecated interface if possible at the old address for one release.

In addition to David's good suggestion, you could also build your own version numbers into the name of the resource service extension if it's better to support multiple versions of an extension in a single modules database.

Answer (score 1):

If this is to have versions of your rest extensions and use the V# in that process, then I think you could have multiple sets of your code deployed in different modules databases (per version) and dynamically switch modules database based on the version and then rewrite the URL after that to play well with MarkLogic's REST API.

http://developer.marklogic.com/features/enhanced-http